# Issue with Google Cloud Java authentication

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am having some issues using Vertex AI in java, I used one of the examples for java and set up all my dependencies. I also added the authentication file to the environmental variables.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=PATH_HERE
```

(PATH_HERE represents where I put path to the JSON file with the credentials)

But when I run the Java program I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at com.testvert.PredictImageClassificationSample.main(PredictImageClassificationSample.java:27)
.....
```

Any help would be appreciated

Info :
Mac OS
Java
Inteliji

I was using the Java Vertex AI [code sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/aiplatform/src/main/java/aiplatform/PredictImageClassificationSample.java)

I tried doing the echo command for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and it returned the correct path I entered

Comment: What kind of credentials is in the file? The client library is expecting Service Account JSON. The error message indicates that you have not correctly set up the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` or that the file's contents are incorrect.

Comment: @JohnHanley The JSON file is the file that I downloaded after I created a key under the service account for the project.

Comment: Is it JSON with the following key: `"type": "service_account",`? If yes, then you have not set up the environment variable correctly. If you are very specific about what you did, we won't have to guess.

Comment: @JohnHanley The file is :
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "ftc-helper-bot",

Comment: env | grep -i google.application   will verify that you have set the req'd env var